# Magento dictionary problem

Tags: language, magento2

I am stuck since a few days on this.

I want to create a new dictionary for Magento. And I followed the instructions here :
https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Using+Translation+Functionality#Dictionary

Command to create the dictionarly

> php -f generator.php -- -d  [-m y] [-o ]
>   php -f generator.php -- --directory= [--magento=y] [--output=]

But when I do launch this command, it shows 'no input file specified'

I run it with a php file containing :

> $out = shell_exec("php -f generator.php --directory=temp");

Is it to do that it can't find the generator.php file ?
Or is it something else ?

Help very much appreciated ! 
Thanks in advance
Kim

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary `generator.php` file is located in `dev/tools/Magento/Tools/I18n/` folder.

To generate complete dictionary:

```
$ php -f dev/tools/Magento/Tools/I18n/generator.php -- -d $(pwd) -m y -o test.csv
```

For specific module:

```
$ php -f dev/tools/Magento/Tools/I18n/generator.php -- -d app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/ -o test.csv
```